# Finding most liked posts in the last day with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating an application with Rails where there are posts that can be liked by users. I created a different table for the likes so I have the following structure.

```
POSTS -> id
      -> title
      -> text
         ...

       belongs_to :user
       has_many :likes

USERS -> id
      -> email
      -> name
         ...

        has_many :posts
        has_many :likes

LIKES -> id
      -> post_id
      -> user_id
         ...

        belongs_to :user
```

Now, in the home page I want to show the most liked posts in the last 24 hours, ordered by how many likes they have. I also use the Kaminari gem that provide pagination to my Post model.

So, what should I use to get posts with these parameters?

```
def popular
    @posts = ?
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have my rails env currently on this computer, but try to play around with this:

```
@posts = Post.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN Likes ON likes.post_id = posts.id 
                     AND likes.created_at >= DATETIME('now', '-1 day')")
                    .group("posts.id").order("COUNT(likes.id) DESC")
```

Comment: I get the following error: `SQLite3::SQLException: near "1": syntax error:`

Comment: see the second :partial: solution

Comment: It worked but it only shows posts that have more than one like. Also, what should I do now to show posts for the last day?

Comment: To show the posts with zero likes also use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. what kind of database are you using? SQLite3?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQLite3 just for testing, after I'll probably use Postgres.

Comment: It's working now. Sorry, I have a last question. For example, if I haven't any post in the last 24 hours, will it show earlier most liked posts? I'm asking this because I'd like to have this behavior and it seems that this is actually happening because the posts I currently have are from 2 days ago.

Comment: it shouldn't have the posts older than one day ago, but you could just look if this gives a `@posts.count == 0` then just show all the posts.